# Stack with 'getMinimum' operation

Tags: java, algorithm, stack

Design a Data Structure SpecialStack that supports all the stack operations like push(), pop(), isEmpty(), isFull() and an additional operation getMin() which should return minimum element from the SpecialStack. All these operations of SpecialStack must be O(1). To implement SpecialStack, you should only use standard Stack data structure and no other data structure like arrays, list, .. etc.

Looking for code review, optimizations, best practices.

```
    public class StackMinimum<T>{
       /*
        * Composition triumphs over inheritance :)
        */
       private final Stack<T> stack1 = new Stack<T>();
       private final Stack<T> stack2 = new Stack<T>();

       public void push(T item) {
           stack1.push(item);
           if (stack2.isEmpty() || ((Comparable<T>) item).compareTo(stack2.peek()) < 0) {
               stack2.push(item);
           }
        }

        public T pop() {
            T item = stack1.pop();
            if (item.equals(stack2.peek())) {
                stack2.pop();
            }
            return item;
        }

        public T peek() {
            return stack1.peek();
        }

        public int size() {
            return stack1.size();
        }

        public T getMinimum () {
            return stack2.peek();
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return stack1.isEmpty();
        }
    }


public class StackMinimumTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        StackMinimum<Integer> stack1 = new StackMinimum<Integer>();
        stack1.push(1);
        stack1.push(2);
        stack1.push(3);

        assertEquals(1, (int)stack1.getMinimum());

        stack1.push(-1);
        assertEquals(-1, (int)stack1.getMinimum());

        stack1.pop();
        assertEquals(1, (int)stack1.getMinimum());

        while(!stack1.isEmpty()) {
            assertEquals(1, (int)stack1.getMinimum());
            stack1.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Use Generics**. `StackMinimum<T extends Comparable<T>>`. **Don't cast**.

Comment: Currently the code is bugged. push 5, 3, 3, then pop, and it will report the minimum as 5. Or push 5, 5 then pop twice : EmptyStackException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a bug: `.getMinimum()` loses track if you push the same new minimum value twice.

You should use both inheritance and composition.

Use inheritance for the "main" stack, because your data structure *is* a stack — one with an extra feature.  That gives you the read-only operations `.peek()`, `.size()`, and `.isEmpty()` for free.

Use composition for the "minimum" stack, as you have currently done.

Comment: Unfortunately `Stack extends Vector`, so I guess you have to implement a lot of other methods (like remove) to keep its behavior consistent.

Comment: Good job spotting the `.getMinimum()` bug. Changing the `<` to `<=` will fix the bug (I think).

Comment: That is the first thing that I noticed. Solution by TheDark works, but a simpler solution would be to always push with the minimum value. So pop will also always pop from minimum stack.

Answer (score 3):

1. I would rename `stack1` to `delegate` and `stack2` to `minimumStack` or something similar to express their purpose and make the code easier to understand.
2. I would use [`ObjectUtils.min`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#min%28T...%29) (or `max`?) instead of

   > ```
   > ((Comparable<T>) item).compareTo(stack2.peek()) < 0)
   > ```

   `compareTo` always forces me to check the javadoc to figure out what does its return value mean.
3. Having a loop in the test method is a test smell: [Conditional Test Logic](http://xunitpatterns.com/Conditional%20Test%20Logic.html)
4. The test does not cover the `peek` nor the `size` method.

Comment: I don't agree with introducing a (fairly weighty) dependency like commons lang for no gain. The return of `compareTo` is very well defined and has been since the dark ages.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Yes, I can accept the first part. Anyway, it's just a single `<dependency>` with Maven. If it's an interview question it shows that the interviewee have some knowledge of the existing libraries (and probably don't reinvent the wheel). Finally, you can still create a similar method in your code to make it readable. I know that `compareTo` is quite old but this does not mean that anyone should memorize that (instead of focusing on business problems). Extracting out the comparison to a helper method (similar to `min`) would express the dev's intent and make maintenance easier.

Comment: Sure, completely agree with extracting `if` conditions into `boolean` methods. Just think there need to be more compelling reasons for including dependencies - although cheap to include with Maven, they have their own maintenance costs.

Answer (score 1):

It looks very good for me, you can use the `extend` keyword on generics to insure type safety and to avoid unnecessary casts. And this is called a `Bounded type`

```
class StackMinimum<T extends Comparable>{
      public void push(T item) {
       stack1.push(item);
       // to need for the cast here
       if (stack2.isEmpty() || item.compareTo(stack2.peek()) < 0) {
           stack2.push(item);
       }
    }
}
```

Only Comparable types will be welcomed in your stack

Comment: Shouldn't this be `Comparable<T>`?

Comment: @codesparkle No, it shouldn't, the type is bounded to T where T is Comparable

Comment: `Comparable` is the *raw usage* of the generic interface [`Comparable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). The language specification says: *The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of generics into the Java programming language is* **strongly discouraged.** (emphasis mine)

Comment: Sorry, forgot the [link to the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)

Comment: This answer is close, but wrong. Raw types should never be used.

Comment: @codesparkle the generic interface should be `Comparable<? super T>` as a superclass of T may be the one implementing Comparable.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, `Stack` extends `Vector`. As such `Stack` is a `List`. The easiest and most readable way to add getMinimum() would be to do this :

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Stack;

public class SpecialStack<T extends Comparable<? super T>> extends Stack<T> {

    public T getMinimum() {
        return Collections.min(this);
    }
}
```

I'm guessing this is homework. As such, you can probably not get around using `Stack` for this exercise, but note that `Stack`, as a subclass of `Vector`, carries synchronized overhead, which in most cases you won't need. So for real life purposes you're better off using `ArrayDeque`, [as even Stack's javadoc suggests itself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).